# Spring boot Data jpa LazyInitializationException for simple table without any Joins - method getById

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-boot-starter

I'm running my app in SpringBootTest. Using IN memory db.

I'm getting error in my spring app when i try to get record from db.

I'm using:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

In this app/test I'm also doing save to db and it works fine.

Db table is build of two simple columns DUMMY_ID and REQUEST.

Error: **Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception. Cannot evaluate .......  $HibernateProxy$JjtlVUy6.toString()**

```
Problematic method -> requestsRepository.getById("dummyId");
```

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface RequestsRepository extends JpaRepository<RequestsEntity, String> {
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Component
@Table(name = "REQUESTS", schema = "", catalog = "")
public class RequestsEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DUMMY_ID")
    private String dummyId;
    @Column(name = "REQUEST")
    private String request;

    public RequestsEntity() {
    }

    public RequestsEntity(String dummyId, String request) {
        this.dummyId = dummyId;
        this.request = request;
    }
}
```

I don't know why getById is failing.

Comment: A relevant topic to your problem is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054193/lazyinitializationexception-in-hibernate-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-sessi), i mean answer of this question.

Comment: I think its not exactly same problem. In my case im saving object to db and then I'm trying to read it. In topic above its working. In My problem not and Im using jpa repository, so without dao.

Comment: You are using getById and you know that there are the problem , i recommend you to check this resource [jpa-getReference-and-findById](https://vladmihalcea.com/entitymanager-find-getreference-jpa/) is really a good article. Because this kind of problem is a very popular one when peoples are working with hibernate

Comment: And also a good article for you [handle-thelazyinitializationexception](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/) of course after above recommended article is is going to be it.

Comment: Still i don't see explanation for my problem. In my case findById or getById doesn't work. Should I create custom Repository implementation and there create method for finding record ? Currently I used auto implementation (SimpleJpaRepository) of jpa repository. Maybe there is a problem with EntityManager ?

Comment: when i trigger findById("dummy_id").get()  directly after save to db it works. But when I autowire repository in different bean and try to read saved object with   findById("dummy_id").get() - it doesn't work.

Comment: Just remove `@Transactional` from repository interface and all is going to work well

Comment: Should I give an answer, why did it help ?

Comment: i created project from scratch - maybe it was ide issue ? not sure but for now everything works fine :)